# couldn't find php.ini file

Tags: php, apache, installation, localhost

I'm trying to Install the `php.ini` file as [mentioned here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_installation_linux.htm)

When I tried to locate that file on my laptop, this is the output.

```
$: locate php.ini
/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
```

so I tried to copy that file tp another location like this:

```
$: sudo cp /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini /usr/local/lib/php.ini 
cp: cannot stat '/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini': No such file or directory
```

So, I checked if the file is there or not, and `ls` couldn't show the file.

```
/etc/php/7.0/apache2$ ls
conf.d
```

there was no `php.ini` file. And it is the same case with the `php.ini` file in `/etc/php/7.0/cli/`

Can someone tell me what exactly is happening? 
and what happens of we don't install php.ini file?

Comment: An easier way is to use apt... `sudo apt install apache2 php7.0 php7.0-cli php7.0-{curl,gd,json,xml,mysql,sqlite} libapache2-mod-php7.0 && service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The php.ini file stores very important configuration settings and it is required for PHP to start. From the tutorial, I it mentions that php.ini is in the PHP zip file that you downloaded. Simply copy the file from the zip file to /usr/local/lib/